# Proving that curvature of a smooth curve alpha satisfies and equation.

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis, mathematical-physics

I'm having trouble starting this problem. my intuition is to express the curvature of alpha as

$$\dfrac{\vert (\alpha ' \times \alpha'')\vert}{\vert \alpha ' \vert^3}.$$

Any help would be appreciated.  [image]

Comment: Start by writing out the tangent vector $T_b$, for $\beta$, and then the normal vector $N_b$ for $\beta$, and then follow the definition of curvature using these. You can edit your posting by clicking on the "edit" button to show us what you've managed to do.

Comment: would the tangent vector of B just be B'/mag(B')?

Comment: Yes, but you should work that out in term of $\alpha$ and $N_\alpha$.

Comment: And $T_\alpha$, of course. Also be careful that $s$ will not be the arclength parameter for $\beta$ so you'll need a chain rule application to find curvature.

Comment: so the tangent of B would be (alpha' -rN' )/( 1-r)

Comment: Always get everything in terms of $T$ and $N$ ... So you're nowhere near done. (By the way, at some point you might find my free differential geometry text helpful. You can find the link on my profile.)

Comment: is Tangent of Beta  = v'T + kv^2N

Comment: where T and N are respect to Alpha

Comment: @TedShifrin:  thanks for the book.  Looks great!

Comment: @JordanReed:   I edited your post to $\LaTeX$ify it!

Comment: @JordanReed: No! What is $N'$? Remember that $\alpha$ *is* arclength parametrizecd.

Comment: @TedShifrin Looks like a great book! I'll have to point my students to it.

Comment: I'm definitely not getting this calculation accurate. would anyone care to show me the correct procedure. please and thank you

Comment: @Jordan: $\beta' = \alpha' - rN' = T - r(-\kappa T) = (1+r\kappa)T$.

Comment: would i then have to find Beta double prime, then cross it with beta prime, and then divide by the magnitude of beta prime cubed?

Comment: what would beta double prime look like?

Comment: i was able to finish this problem after some review on chain rule. Thanks for all your help!